# Docker Locust locustfile.py not found

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, locust

I need to create an image from https://hub.docker.com/r/locustio/locust that contains the locustfile.py.

I use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM locustio/locust:1.1.1
ADD locustfile.py /mnt/locust
RUN pip3 install ...
```

Then I build the image:

`docker build -t mylocustimage locust/.`

And I try to use it in my docker-compose.yml:

```
locust-master:
    image: mylocustimage
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py -H http://localhost --logfile=locustfile.log
```

But every time I try to start the container it fails with this error:

> Could not find any locustfile! Ensure file ends in '.py' and see --help for available options.

Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the trailing slash, you need to do:

```
ADD locustfile.py /mnt/locust/
```

... otherwise locustfile.py will be saved to the image as literally `/mnt/locust` instead of `/mnt/locust/locustfile.py`